# Question on the Gell-Mann Low equation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory, interactions, ground-state

Question on the [Gell-Mann Low Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gell-Mann_and_Low_theorem).

In this paper, http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.3365, page 21, the author argues that if $t\to\infty(1-i\epsilon)$, all the terms in equation (193),
$$
\mathrm e^{-iH(t+t_0)}|0\rangle=\mathrm e^{-iE_0(t+t_0)}|\Omega\rangle\langle\Omega|0\rangle+\sum_{n\neq 0}^\infty\mathrm e^{-iE_n(t+t_0)}|n_I\rangle\langle n_i|0\rangle
$$
go to zero, except the first term.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: If you substitute $t\rightarrow \tau (1-i\epsilon) $ in your eq. (193), then the exponent is no longer a pure phase (i.e. complex number wuth modulus =1). All the terms receive a factor of type $e^{-\tau E_n}$. All these terms go to zero, as $\tau \rightarrow \infty$, but since author says $E_n > E_0$ for all $n>0$, then the first term goes to zero _slower_ than all other terms. Thus we keep only this first term. _If you understand now, then you can make it your own answer, [it is ok to answer your questions.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions)_